# Allowing users to run script via /etc/sudoers and permissions

Tags: macos, shell, sudoers

I'd like users in staff group who do not have admin/root permissions to run the following script without being prompted for a password. This is in OSX.

Note that /usr/sbin/serveradmin requires root/sudo privileges.

I've tried adding the following to my /etc/sudoers, but it does not work. Script has permissions of 755.

```
%staff ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/serveradmin stop smb,/usr/sbin/serveradmin start smb
%staff ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /opt/scripts/restart-smb
```

Here's the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script simply restarts SMB (Samba)
#
echo "Stopping SMB..."
/usr/sbin/serveradmin stop smb
echo "Pausing for 30 seconds..."
/bin/sleep 30
echo "Starting SMB..."
/usr/sbin/serveradmin start smb
echo "Script complete!"
```

Your ideas, suggestions most appreciated!

Dan

Comment: Have you tried specifying who the commands are to be run as, so your rule in sudo would be %staff ALL=(root)NOPASSWD: ...etc?

Answer (score 8):

WARNING while playing with the /etc/sudoers file managing users privilege and permissions, I **CRASHED** Ubuntu.

Normal login was not possible anymore. I got a parsing error coming from a simple space missing between # and % character in a line I wrongly commented #%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /pathtoscripts/script.sh . 
I had to recover it with the install/liveCD mounting again the hardrive filesystem, put back the original file in place and dismount the volume for recording changes.

For the above reason I would **NOT RECOMMEND THIS METHOD** first because it modifies /etc/sudoers privileges critical file. Choose first alternatives available unless:

- you have a good back up of your data outside of your PC
- you are not afraid to take the risk to repair/reinstall your system
- you know the **RIGHT SYNTAX** of the /etc/sudoers file, trials and parsing errors could cost you a lot of time and/or efforts/crashes...

Reading the other posts, I managed to get it work on my system, managing permissions through a group:

I created the group mygroup

```
sudo groupadd mygroup
```

I added the user myuser which will execute the script

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup myuser
```

I added at the **END** of /etc/sudoers the entry, otherwise the privilege are overwritten by the previous lines (be careful with syntax)

```
%mygroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

The above script myscript.sh must have execute permission

```
sudo ugo+x /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

This script will then be able to be launched by the user myuser directly as below wihtout prompting for password anymore

```
sudo /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

Alternatively, the script can be launched within another one in a same way

---

I found another way without creating a group, adding to /etc/sudoers file (at the **END** of file) the line:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

---

In case the script must only be launched by a few existing users myuser1, myuser2, it is always possible to  only add to /etc/sudoers (at the **END** of file) the lines :

```
myuser1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh

myuser2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /mypath/to/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Some (many?) Linux systems have a _visudo_ command to edit /etc/sudoers* files. This minimizes the chance of making your system inoperable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by adding the following to my /etc/sudoers file:

```
%staff ALL=/opt/scripts/restart-smb
```

Then of course making the script executable (I had forgotten that).

Still requires a password (which is okay), but working.